# reactive firestore repository not emitting new values on flux endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-data, spring-webflux

I have exposed an endpoint which gives stream of users i.e. whenever a new user has been inserted it should emit that.

**Problem:** This returns all the preexisting users but if I am adding new user from firestore console it is not emitting new inserted value.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @GetMapping(path = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
  public Flux<User> getUsers() {

    return userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

Repository interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<User> {

}
```

User entity

```
@Document(collectionName = "users")
public class User {

  @DocumentId
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

Sample user webclient to test stream of users:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserClient {

  @Bean
  WebClient getWebClient() {
    return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
  }

  @Bean
  CommandLineRunner demo(WebClient client) {
    return args -> {
      client.get()
          .uri("/users")
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToFlux(User.class)
          .subscribe(user -> {
            log.info(user.toString());
          });
    };
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(UserClient.class).properties(java.util.Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8081"))
        .run(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to do that? Your underlying repository is just going to be running a query when you call `findAll()`, and then sending the results back in a non-blocking fashion. It's not going to be constantly running queries, or keeping a connection open to the database in case any new users are added later.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I got your point. Then how can we achieve http streaming to listen to the underlying database changes.

Comment: Your underlying database would need to support sending out those changes as a stream - I'm not aware of any that can do that. You'd probably need to drive that directly from whatever was sending those user creation requests to the database instead.